# Saber a frequência de palavras

Tags: r

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe alguma função/comando no R que eu consiga saber quais são as palavras mais frequentes em um texto e quantas vezes ela aparece.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um banco de dados muito grande, porem é um banco de dados em que cada linha são textos.

E eu gostaria de saber quais são as palavras que possuem maior frequência no meu banco de dados, e quantas vezes elas aparecem.

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se há uma função para isso, mas certa vez eu usei o código sugerido [neste tutorial](http://johnvictoranderson.org/?p=115) para fazer essa contagem. O código final do tutorial é esse (não é exatamente o código do tutorial, mas o que eu usei adaptado):

```
texto <- scan("oslusiadas.txt", what="char", sep="\n", encoding = "UTF-8")
texto <- tolower(texto)

lista_palavras <- strsplit(texto, "\\W+")
vetor_palavras <- unlist(lista_palavras)

frequencia_palavras <- table(vetor_palavras)
frequencia_ordenada_palavras <- sort(frequencia_palavras, decreasing=TRUE)

palavras <- paste(names(frequencia_ordenada_palavras), frequencia_ordenada_palavras, sep=";")

cat("Palavra;Frequencia", palavras, file="frequencias.csv", sep="\n")
```

Nesse teste eu contei as palavras do poema "Os Lusíadas", disponível na [página do projeto Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/3333/pg3333.txt). No arquivo texto utilizado eu retirei as cláusulas de licença e outros textos em inglês, deixando apenas o poema. As duas primeiras linhas do código fazem a leitura do arquivo (em Unicode, já que o texto contém caracteres acentuados) e normalizam o texto (convertendo tudo para minúsculo). As duas linhas seguintes fazem a separação em palavras em um vetor, as próximas duas linhas fazem a contagem da frequência (quanto cada palavra aparece) e ordenam essa contagem de forma descendente (as palavras que mais aparecem são colocadas primeiro). É importante não utilizar o "formato Pearl" na expressão regular usada na função [`strsplit`](http://web.mit.edu/r_v3.0.1/lib/R/library/base/html/strsplit.html), pois ele não trata corretamente as palavras acentuadas (isto é, use `pearl=FALSE` ou não use o parâmetro, já que falso é o valor *default*). E, por fim, a última linha salva o resultado em um arquivo texto (eu usei o ponto-e-vírgula como separador).

O resultado é algo assim, e o arquivo pode ser importado no Excel (por exemplo):

```
Palavra;Frequencia
que;2741
e;2221
o;1953
a;1858
de;1438
se;981
os;750
;742
do;627
não;585
com;574
por;538
em;519
as;516
da;487
lhe;401
no;326
já;309
mais;283
mas;283
na;252
um;239
quem;232
ao;231
gente;230
dos;227
terra;222
tão;210
para;205
rei;204
como;195
mar;188
onde;177
the;176
é;160
seu;155
[...]
```

Comment: Muito obrigada :D

Comment: Luíz, nãe é grave mas parece-me que a tua solução está a dar palavras estranhas (nã, jã). (problemas utf8?)

Comment: @JJoao Rapaz, vc tem razão. Obrigado por notar e avisar. :) Já vou fazer a correção pra usar Unicode no processamento.

Comment: Boa +1 pelos lusíadas.

Answer (score 3):

A ideia é dividir todas as linhas do seu texto em palavras (por exemplo, usando `strsplit`), concatenar todas as palavras e contar as instâncias de cada uma delas (por exemplo, usando `table`). O código abaixo mostra uma possível implementação:

```
contaPalavras <- function(linhas) {
    palavras <- strsplit(linhas, "\\W+")
    todas <- unlist(palavras)
    contagem <- table(todas)
    contagem[order(-contagem)]
}
linhas <- c(
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.",
    "Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.",
    "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.",
    "Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue.",
    "Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy.",
    "Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla.",
    "Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien. Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat.",
    "Etiam eget dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed at lorem in nunc porta tristique.",
    "Proin nec augue. Quisque aliquam tempor magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
    "Nunc ac magna. Maecenas odio dolor, vulputate vel, auctor ac, accumsan id, felis. Pellentesque cursus sagittis felis.")
contaPalavras(linhas)
```

Note que você provavelmente irá querer remover palavras que você não quer contar, como artigos, conjunções, preposições, etc., mas isso depende das regras do seu negócio.

Comment: Muito obrigada :D

Answer (score 1):

O pacote [`tokenizers`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tokenizers) ajuda a fazer isso de um jeito bem fácil!

Exemplo:

```
library(tokenizers)

tokenize_words(linhas, lowercase = FALSE) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  table() %>%
  sort(decreasing = TRUE)
```

O legal do `tokenizers` é que ele já faz alguns tratamentos como transformar tudo em minúsculo, retirar pontuação, etc.

Além disso, ele possui outras funções como `tokenizer_ngrams` que ao invés de contar palavras, contaria combinações de palavras.